# Custom sort of featured products in woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Can any body please help me to sort the featured products only using different sorting attributes like price,date in woo-commerce.
I have tried the code

```
  function sort_by()
   {
   $args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'product',  
    'meta_key' => '_featured',  
    'meta_value' => 'yes',  
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'orderby' => $_POST['sorter'] ,
    'order'=>'ASC'  
   );   
    $featured_query = new WP_Query( $args );  
    print_r($featured_query); 
    if ($featured_query->have_posts()) :   

    while ($featured_query->have_posts()) : 

        $featured_query->the_post();            
        $product = get_product( $featured_query->post->ID );  

          echo the_title();

         endwhile; 
    endif;    
    wp_reset_query(); // Remember to reset  
    die();
    }
add_action('wp_ajax_sort_by','sort_by');
add_action('wp_ajax_no-prev_sort_by','sort_by');
```

The above code works when ajax hit but it's cannot sort the feature products according to date, price, popularity and rating.

Comment: `price`, `popularity` and `rating` are meta_keys of WooCommerce you have to use `meta_query` within your `$args`. Read [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: Thanks Rahil, i am newbie to wordpress, can you please describe more.
Thanks in advance..